# How to calculate $f'(0)$ and $f'$ $(\sqrt{2})$ while $f(x)$= $\int_{x}^{x^3} e^{t^{2}}dt\ $?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate $f'(0)$ and $f'$ $(\sqrt{2})$ while $f(x)$= $\int_{x}^{x^3} e^{t^{2}}dt\  $?

I thought about using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but im not sure im fully aware of how to use it in this case.

any kind of help/directing, would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know [Leibniz's integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you use the fundamental theorem. Let $F(x) = \int_a^x e^{t^2}\ dt$. Then

$$f(x) = F(x^3)-F(x) = \int_x^{x^3} e^{t^2} \ dt$$

So

$$f'(x) = F'(x^3)\cdot 3x^2 - F'(x)$$

where by the fundamental theorem,

$$F'(x) = e^{x^2}$$

Comment: Lets suggest that $f(x)$ = $\int_{0}^{x^2-3x} (2 + sint^2) dt$ , what function would u suggest at the beginning for $F(x)$?

Comment: It's the same idea, $F(x)=\int_a^x (2+\sin t^2)\ dt$. Then $f(x) = F(x^2-3x)-F(0)$. Or, you could just pick $a=0$ and use $f(x)=F(x^2-3x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Some hints. The Fundamental Theorem says that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\int_0^ue^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=e^{u^2}\tag{1}
$$
Let $u=x^3$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^ue^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\int_0^ue^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=3x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\int_0^ue^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Then note that
$$
\int_x^ue^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^ue^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{3}
$$